# Pandoc not converting Markdown list to LaTeX properly

Tags: conversion, latex, markdown, pandoc, pdflatex

I cannot seem to get Pandoc to convert my Markdown documents to PDF (via LaTeX) properly. The problem seems to come from how I am formatting my lists. If I use the following command `pandoc -i test.md -t latex -o test.pdf`, I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.57   F

pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
```

Here's 'test.md':

```
Options

* First
* Second
* Third
```

However, if I remove the blank line between `Options` and the list, I can get it to convert, but with all of the options concatenated onto a single line.

What do I need to do to make a Markdown list render properly when converting to PDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem was that I thought `-i` meant input, when it actually means `--incremental`. Executing the following command works since Pandoc assumes the first parameter is the input file: `pandoc test.md -o test.pdf`. Pandoc also figures out the format to export to, so `-t latex` is unnecessary.